# How to write this for loop as map function

Tags: python, loops

I read that `map` can be used more efficiently for iterations than `for loops`. How would I use `map` on this `for loop`:

```
import time
start = time.time()

L = []
a = 5
b = 0
for i in range(1000):
    L.append(i)
    b +=a


print(L)
print(b)
end = time.time()
print(end-start)
```

Comment: `map` makes sense if you start with a list of items, and then want to independently apply a function to each element of that list.  That doesn't appear to be the case here.

Comment: Have you tried to write it yourself? Which parts did you have trouble with? Can you show us your map code that's not working?

Comment: For loops usually do one of 4 things: transform, search, filter, or aggregate. Your loop is doing 2 of these. `map` is a transform.

Comment: You could do `L = map(None, range(1000))` and `b = a*len(L)`. But the first one is silly, and the second part is, well, math.

Comment: "I read that map can be used more efficiently for iterations than for loops" only in certain cases and even in those cases it is marginally faster. Often, it is slower.

Comment: For the type of thing that you're trying to do, a _list comprehension_ **may** be faster. But you've got a bit confused from your reading about what `map` does.

Comment: I thought I could use it for large iterations which include calculation to make it more efficient, but I take that it is out of place here. Thanks for the quick responses!

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov generally, map is not particularly more efficient than a for-loop. When using built-in functions, something like `map(int, list_of_strings)` it can be faster, but in general, it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *really* want to use `map`:

```
L = []
a, b = 5, 0

list(map(L.append, range(1000)))
# or sum(map(bool, map(L.append, range(1000)))) - doesn't waste memory

b = a * len(L)
```

Note that for the calls to `L.append` to be executed, you need to *iterate* over the output of `map`, which is what `list` and `sum` do in this code.

You don't need use it in this case, however. This looks and performs better:

```
L = list(range(1000))
```

If you're using Python 2, you could just do `L = range(1000)`.